Database/Model design if some of many-to-many relations can be exclusive
Let's say we have Articles many2many Tags, with additional fields in the middle ArticleToTag table (like createdAt).
However some Tags are considered Exclusive, and Article can have only one Exclusive Tag. But otherwise Exclusive Tags have exact same fields as regular Tags, and the connection has exact same fields as well.
So here are several options:

Have Tag and ExclusiveTag as different entities with same fields.
Have Article many2one ExclusiveTag, and duplicate additional ArticleToTag fields in the Article.


++ completely error-proof at the db level
++ no need for any code
-- lots of duplication at the db level
-- if you want to change a Tag to Exclusive, all the previous records require update

Have Exclusive Tags as just Tags with isExclusive flag field.

Do everything at the ORM level.
++ zero duplication at the db level
++ if you want to change a Tag to Exclusive, all the previous records do not require update
-- not error-proof at the db level
-- needs lots of code

Have Exclusive Tags as just Tags with isExclusive flag field.
Have Article one2one ArticleToTag.


== almost error-proof at the db level
== needs only a bit of code
== almost no duplication
-- can't cascade persist because of circular reference - you have to persist the Article first, then persist the ArticleToTag and update the Article

Use ORM inheritance for ExclusiveTag and ArticleToExclusiveTag.
Have Article one2one ArticleToExclusiveTag.


== the same as the previous option at the db level
++ error-proof and requires no code at the ORM level
++ can cascade persist
Is it the common problem, and is there a consensus for the optimal solution?


However some Tags are considered Exclusive, and Article can have only one Exclusive Tag. But otherwise Exclusive Tags have exact same fields as regular Tags, and the connection has exact same fields as well.

Just have a flag attribute (a boolean field) in Tags that says which tags are "exclusive".  Then you will need in ArticleToTag, beside the various FKs, a check constraint such that at most one "exclusive" Tag is associated to any one Article at any time, which you can implement with a table-level constraint (no trigger should be necessary here, just a table constraint, but the fine print may vary depending on the specific DBMS).
